# In responsive design, dragging and dropping does not work in wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop

I am making one quiz type page in wordpress which has two dropzones. One contains list of buttons and other one is empty. User has to drag and drop the buttons from first dropzone to other. I have created this code in html,css,js and included it in contact form 7. And using cf7 shortcode I have included it in my page. This quiz should be responsive so I have tried below code. It works on browser but not in device.

```js
var orderNos = [];

function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
  console.log("event.target.id", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  console.log("event.target.value", event.target.value);
  orderNos.push(data);
  document.getElementById("orderNos").value = orderNos;
  console.log("drp", orderNos);
}

function reset() {
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
}
```

```css
.drop-zone {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px dashed #000000;
}

.droptarget {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 430px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px dashed #000000;
}

:root {
  --bg-table-stripe: #f6f6f5;
  --b-table: #e3e3e2;
  --caption: #242423;
}

table {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

th {
  text-align: left
}

.dcf-txt-center {
  text-align: center!important
}

.dcf-txt-left {
  text-align: left!important
}

.dcf-txt-right {
  text-align: right!important
}

.dcf-table caption {
  color: var(--caption);
  font-size: 1.13em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: .56rem
}

.dcf-table thead {
  font-size: .84em
}

.dcf-table tbody {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--b-table);
  border-top: 1px solid var(--b-table);
  font-size: .84em
}

.dcf-table tfoot {
  font-size: .84em
}

.dcf-table td,
.dcf-table th {
  padding-right: 1.78em
}

.dcf-table-bordered,
.dcf-table-bordered td,
.dcf-table-bordered th {
  border: 1px solid var(--b-table)
}

.dcf-table-bordered td,
.dcf-table-bordered th,
.dcf-table-striped td,
.dcf-table-striped th {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em
}

.dcf-table-bordered tr:not(:last-child),
.dcf-table-striped tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--b-table)
}

.dcf-table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: var(--bg-table-stripe)
}

.dcf-table thead td,
.dcf-table thead th {
  padding-bottom: .75em;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.dcf-table tbody td,
.dcf-table tbody th,
.dcf-table tfoot td,
.dcf-table tfoot th {
  padding-top: .75em;
  vertical-align: top
}

.dcf-table tbody td,
.dcf-table tbody th {
  padding-bottom: .75em
}

.dcf-table-bordered thead th {
  padding-top: 1.33em
}

.dcf-wrapper-table-scroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
  width: 100vw
}

@media only screen and (max-width:42.09em) {
  .dcf-table-responsive thead {
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive tr {
    display: block
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive td {
    -webkit-column-gap: 3.16vw;
    -moz-column-gap: 3.16vw;
    column-gap: 3.16vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    text-align: left!important
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive.dcf-table-bordered,
  .dcf-table-responsive.dcf-table-bordered thead th {
    border-width: 0
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive.dcf-table-bordered tbody td {
    border-top-width: 0
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive:not(.dcf-table-bordered) tbody tr {
    padding-bottom: .75em
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive:not(.dcf-table-bordered) tbody td {
    padding-bottom: 0
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive:not(.dcf-table-bordered):not(.dcf-table-striped) tbody td {
    padding-right: 0
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive.dcf-table-bordered tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 0
  }
  .dcf-table-responsive tbody td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right: 1.78em
  }
}

.dcf-overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto!important;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
}

.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

input {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 200px;
  animation-name: button;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.input-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: button-text;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.gradient-button {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.gradient-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  margin: 8px 10px 12px;
}

.gradient-button-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #DD5E89 0%, #F7BB97 0%, #DD5E89 100%);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.gradient-button-1:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}

.gradient-button-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2BC0E4 0%, #EAECC6 0%, #2BC0E4 100%);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.gradient-button-2:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}

.gradient-button-3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7474BF 0%, #348AC7 0%, #7474BF 100%);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.gradient-button-3:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}

.gradient-button-4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00d2ff 0%, #3a7bd5 0%, #00d2ff 100%);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: inherit;
}

.gradient-button-4:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table class="dcf-table dcf-table-responsive dcf-table-bordered dcf-table-striped dcf-w-100% center">
    <caption>quiz</caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="dcf-txt-center">
        <div class="droptarget" id="dragBox" style="border-color:#DE4031;" ondrop="drop(event)">
          <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="Miscommunication&Misinterpretation">Miscommunication & Misinterpretation  </button>
          <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="CommunicationDelays">Communication Delays </button>
          <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="ScatteredWorkandContent">Scattered Work and Content  </button>
          <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="SharingWorkwithOthers">Sharing Work with Others  </button>
          <button class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="GettingFeedbackandIdeas">Getting Feedback and Ideas  </button>
          <input type="text" class="gradient-button-4" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" placeholder="Any Other?" id="anyOther" />
        </div>
        <div class="droptarget" id="dropBox" style="border-color:#31CFDE" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        </div>
      </tr>
      <tr class="dcf-txt-center">
        <div><button id="reset" onclick="reset();">Reset</button></div>
        <!-- [email emailId id:emailId placeholder "Enter your business email Id"] -->
        <div><button id="submit" onclick="">Submit</button></div>
        </td>
        <!-- [hidden clicked_on_link clicked_on_link id:clicked_on_link "No"]
    [hidden orderNos orderNos id:orderNos]
    [hidden submission_id submission_id id:submission_id "1"] -->
        </th>
        <td class="dcf-txt-center">
          <input type="email" id:emailId placeholder "Enter your business email Id">
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

In responsive mode drag and drop is not working. Please help me to fix this problem.